# Using Vuelidate, how to generate error if what the user inputs already exists in db?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

I'm creating a form using Vue JS, more specifically the Vuetify framework.

I've already created a way to show an error when an item doesn't exist, however how can I make it so that it also shows an error if what the user enters already exists in the database?

```
    data: () => ({
        aRule: [
            v => !! v || 'Please provide project type',
        ],
    }),
```

My form component looks like this:

```
    <v-text-field
        :rules="aRule"
        label="Project Type"
        v-model="choice.data"
    >
    </v-text-field>
```

Please note that 'choice.data' represents the data column in the database

Comment: [Asynchronous validation](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-asynchronous-validation) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The rule should be like this

```
emailRules = [
    v: => !!v || "email address is required",
    v: => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || "Please input a valid email",
    v: => (v && this.doesUserExist != true) || "Email already exists.",
  ];
```

initialize doesUserExist = null;
set this.doesUserExist = true; , when server response user already exist.